# How to deploy Django app from local machine on 'Django: certified by Bitnami' on AWS?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, web-applications

I have created a Django app which works well on my computer. I want to deploy it on AWS EC2 (on t2.micro). (There is an official guide for AWS Beanstalk (but it doesn't come under free tier)

I have an EC2 instance running which has Django certified by Bitnami stack on it, it shows the successful installation screen:
[image: screenshot of the website when i visit it]

There isn't much documentation on it and no detailed tutorials available, since not many people are using it . How can I deploy the django app from my local machine (which has the database in it, currently having hundreds of rows) onto this EC2 instance?

Comment: Did you check this page https://docs.bitnami.com/oci/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/

Comment: What have you tried? What specific issue are you facing?

Comment: their documentation isn't properly written. they make stacks for several softwares, and copy-paste the documentation pieces for each of them. How do I even create a new superuser? how do I edit the views.py/urls.py etc files ? I was using VS code for editing locally